# Qual o uso de ponteiros de ponteiros?

Tags: c++

Qual o uso de ponteiros de ponteiros,exemplo:

```
int  var;
int  *p;
int  **pp;
var = 50;
```

Até compreendo o uso do ponteiro simples(*),mas para que usar outro para referenciar este?

Comment: Um uso comum e criar listas ligadas, por exemplo. De uma lida [nisso](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html), e bastante didatico.

Comment: Incrivelmente essa era uma das guias que acabei de abrir...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Vamos supor um computador de 8 bits com endereços 8 bits e que tenha apenas 256 bytes de memória. Essa é parte da memória, os números acima representam os endereços:

```
 54   55   56   57   58   59   60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    | 58 |    |    | 63 |    | 55 |    |    | h  | e  | l  | l  | o  | \0 |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Podemos notar que no endereço 63 começa a string "hello". Então nesse caso, se essa é a única ocorrência de "hello" na memória então,

```
const char *c = "hello";
```

... define `c` como o ponteiro read-only (somente de leitura) da string "hello", e contem o valor 63. `c` deve estar armazenado em algum lugar: no exemplo acima está localizado no endereço 58. Além de apontar para caracteres, mas também podemos apontar para ponteiros. EX:

```
const char **cp = &c;
```

Agora `cp` aponta para `c`, Isso é, Ele contém o endereço de `c` (que é 58).Considere também:

```
const char ***cpp = &cp;
```

Agora `cpp` armazena o endereço de `cp`. Então o seu valor é 55 baseado no exemplo acima, E ele mesmo armazena o endereço 60.

Agora o motivo de ter ponteiros de ponteiros:

- O nome de um array fornece o endereço do seu primeiro elemento. Então se o array contem elementos do tipo `t`, uma referência para o array tem o tipo `t *`. Agora considere um array de arrays do tipo `t`: naturalmente uma referência para esse array 2D será do tipo `(t *)*`, que é o mesmo que `t **`, e é consequentemente um ponteiro de ponteiro.
- Mesmo que um array de strings soa como 1D, na verdade é 2D, já que as strings são arrays de caracteres. Consequentemente: `char **`.
- Uma funçao `f` terá que aceitar um parâmetro do tipo `t **` se é para alterar a variável do tipo `t *`.

Entre outras muitas utilidades.

Essas informações foram traduzidas [deste post do Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c).

Comment: Boa resposta. Mas me parece que há um errinho na frase "E ele mesmo armazena o endereço 60.". Ela dá a impressão que o ponteiro `cpp` contém o valor `60`, mas você não quis dizer que ele está *alocado* no endereço `60`?

Answer (score 9):

Um dos principais usos de `int **p` é a construção de matrizes. Um ponteiro `int *p` pode apontar para um array de inteiros (vários inteiros em posições contíguas de memória) e um "ponteiro para ponteiro" pode apontar para um um array de ponteiros, cada um deles apontando para um array de inteiros. Repare que com isso consegue fazer uma matriz (um array de arrays) com linhas de tamanho diferente.

Além disso, outro uso comum é para passar o ponteiro como referência para uma função. Dessa forma você consegue passar uma estrutura como parâmetro para uma função e ela pode alterar para onde seu ponteiro aponta internamente (como fazendo apontar para outro lugar porque teve que utilizar malloc internamente para aumentar o tamanho dela).