# C++ classe com vários construtores - Arquivo header e cpp

Tags: c++, qt

Tenho uma classe em C++ onde tenho dois construtores. No arquivo minhaclasse.h:

```
public:
  MinhaClasse(int x1);
  MinhaClasse(int x1, int x2);
```

Depois no arquivo minhaclasse.cpp crio normalmente os construtores que declarei ali no header. Até aqui tudo bem. O problema acontece agora na minha classe Main. No arquivo header da classe Main, quero declarar dentro de public:

```
public:
  MinhaClasse classe;
```

Porém se eu rodar o projeto nesse ponto, a linha acima dá erro, dizendo que há uma ambiguidade, pois como não inicializei o objeto classe, e ele não sabe que construtor usar.
A única maneira que fiz e que funcionou foi não declarar o objeto dentro do Header, e deixar pra declara-lo inteiro já dentro do CPP:

```
 MinhaClasse classe = MinhaClasse(5);
```

Então chego à minha pergunta: se a classe `MinhaClasse` possui dois construtores, tem algum "macete" para, na minha classe `Main`, poder declarar o objeto 'classe' dentro do Header, sem inicializa-lo, ou nesse caso vou precisar realmente não criar o objeto no header e deixar pra declara-lo completamente dentro do CPP??

Arquivo calculadora.h

```
#ifndef CALCULADORA_H
#define CALCULADORA_H
class Calculadora
{
public:
    Calculadora(int x=0);
    Calculadora(int x=0, int y=0);
};
#endif // CALCULADORA_H
```

Arquivo calculadora.cpp:

```
#include "calculadora.h"
#include "qdebug.h"
Calculadora::Calculadora(int x)
{
    qDebug() << x;
}
Calculadora::Calculadora(int x, int y)
{
    qDebug() << x+y;
}
```

E no mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "calculadora.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Calculadora calc; // aqui dá o erro!!!!
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de "executar" diretamente a chamada da classe com:

```
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Calculadora calc; // aqui dá o erro!!!!
```

Faça assim:

```
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Calculadora *calc;
```

E no CPP chame assim:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    calc = new Calculadora();
}
```

Leia mais em:

- [Qual o uso de ponteiros de ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25359/3635)

### Erro call of overloaded is ambiguous

O que ocorre é que quando você tenta definir parametros padrões ele não consegue se decidir qual usar.

Ao invés disto:

```
public:
    Calculadora(int x=0);
    Calculadora(int x=0, int y=0);
```

Faça isto:

```
public:
    Calculadora(int x=0);
    Calculadora(int x, int y);
```

Comment: Agora sim funcionou!!!! Vou tentar entender melhor os ponteiros, pois pra mim é um conceito novo. Agradeço demais sua atenção e paciência!

Comment: @PauloLuvisoto Se a resposta lhe resolveu o problema por favor marque-a como correta clicando no botão verde (abaixo dos pontos da resposta) como Correta. Obrigado

Comment: A resposta está correta e muito boa. Mas acho que ela poderia ser melhorada com alguns detalhes: (1) Como a classe `Calculadora` do exemplo não herda de `QObject`, o ponteiro criado deveria ser deletado para evitar vazamentos de memória. Dificilmente isso vai ser um problema se essa classe é criada/usada apenas na janela principal, mas é no mínimo bom tomar ciência do caso. (2) Uma alternativa para não precisar usar ponteiros é definir um construtor padrão (default) e *setters* para os parâmetros. Assim a classe pode ser declarada estaticamente e os parâmetros alterados no `main`.

Comment: @LuizVieira eu tinha falado sobre isto, mas removi da resposta pois o autor parece estar iniciando no aprendizado de classes, mas vou re-adicionar :) assim que possivel.

Comment: Entendi. Bom, o AP já marcou como aceita, então acho que pra ele já foi de ajuda suficiente. Se adicionar, acho que fica como uma ajuda melhor para outras pessoas também. :)

Comment: Apesar de já conhecer programação à um tempo considerável, o C++ me trouxe alguns conceitos novos, que estou tendo que assimilar. Estou de olho em tudo o que vocês estão comentando pra ver o que mais posso absorver.