# Passando por referência em C

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, referência

No caso da linguagem C, quando desejamos passar uma variável por referência precisamos passar o endereço dela à função, tenho uma dúvida nesse caso.

Veja o exemplo:

```
int main(){
   int *a;
   *a = 5;
   foo(&a);
}


void foo(int **a){
 //tenho que passar o endereço para garantir a mudança?
   bar(&a);
}

void bar(int ***a){
 //como atribuir? ***a = 1; ??
}
```

A minha dúvida é a seguinte, se desejo passar por referência um ponteiro para uma variável é necessário sempre passar o endereço do que tenho no escopo da função para garantir que o resultado seja alterado?

Se sim nesse caso, como atribuo o valor quando tenho `**a` ou `***a` ?

Existe um outra abordagem? Como facilitar esse controle?

Comment: O que você está tentando fazer de verdade? Isso é importante para saber se você tem que passar o endereço da variável como um ponteiro, ou o endereço do ponteiro como um ponteiro de ponteiro, ou o endereço do ponteiro de ponteiro como um ponteiro de ponteiro de ponteiro. Se você chegar em um ponto aonde precise manipular ponteiros de ponteiros de ponteiros, provavelmente está fazendo algo errado. Normalmente, basta apenas um nível de "ponteirismo" e raramente dois.

Comment: tive um trabalho da faculdade no qual implementamos listas e filas, então basicamente passa um ponteiro de ponteiro para a primeira função, ou seja tinhamos **p, se dentro dessa função eu quisesse modificar um dado da minha fila eu teria que passar o endereço do ponteiro de ponteiro? Ou apenas passando o ponteiro de ponteiro seria suficiente?

Comment: O segredo para garantir a passagem de parâmetros por referencia é ser um ponteiro do que voce originalmente atribuiu?

Comment: A minha dúvida é se em um determinado escopo (função) eu precisar passar uma estrutura que tenho ali (no caso foi recebido como argumento dessa tal função) para outra função por referência, eu preciso mandar o endereço do que recebi por argumento? ou seja, recebi *p , terei que passar o ponteiro para essa estrutura? No caso **p?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Precisas de `malloc()` antes de usar o ponteiro.
2. Nao precisas de estar sempre a acrescentar um nivel de indireccao em cada funcao nova: basta mandares o endereco da primeira vez e depois reusar esse endereco.
3. A declaracao de objectos segue o uso: `int *a` quer dizer que `*a` é um `int`; `int *****b` quer dizer que `*****b` é um `int`.

Se queres meter um valor num objecto de type `int ***` usa `***a`.

Ve este codigo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(int **a, int *b);
void bar(int ***a, int *b);

int main(void) {
    int *a;
    int b;
    a = malloc(sizeof *a);
    if (a) {
        *a = b = 5;
        printf("antes de foo(): %d, %d\n", *a, b);
        foo(&a, &b);
        printf("depois de foo(): %d, %d\n", *a, b);
        free(a);
    }
}


void foo(int **a, int *b) {
    // tenho que passar o endereço para garantir a mudança?
    printf("antes de bar(): %d, %d\n", **a, *b);
    bar(&a, b);
    printf("depois de bar(): %d, %d\n", **a, *b);
}

void bar(int ***a, int *b) {
    ***a = *b = 42;
}
```

Comment: Quando chegar em casa testarei, mas no caso o valor será o mesmo, certo? Obrigado por responder.

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa usar ponteiro para ponteiro, basta usar um ponteiro "simples". Para entender mais sobre poteiros, sugiro estas outras duas perguntas:

- [Didática simples de Ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26633/did%C3%A1tica-simples-de-ponteiros)
- [Qual o uso de ponteiros de ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25359/qual-o-uso-de-ponteiros-de-ponteiros)

Eu refiz o seu código pra ele funcionar como você deseja:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bar(int *a){
    *a = 1;
}

void foo(int *a){
    bar(a);
}

int main(){
   int a;
   a = 5;
   foo(&a);
   printf("a = %d\n", a);
   return 0;
}
```

Ambas as funções esperam como parâmetro um ponteiro para um inteiro (`int *a`). A função `foo` simplesmente repassa ele para a outra (porque seus parâmetros têm o mesmo tipo de dados). Note porém:

1. Na função `main` eu não declarei um ponteiro, e sim uma variável "normal". Na chamada `foo(&a)` eu uso o operador `&` para indicar que eu quero passar ali o *endereço da variável `a`*.
2. Na função `bar` eu atualizo o conteúdo de uma área "apontada" por um ponteiro fazendo o seguinte: `*a = 1`. Isso significa basicamente "atribui 1 à área de memória apontada por `a`".

Ou seja, sempre que você vê `&algo` você está pegando o endereço da área de memória onde `algo` está alocado. Sempre que você vê `*algo` você está de fato acessando esse endereço (tanto para ler como para alterar).

P.S.: Eu inverti a ordem das funções para o compilador não reclamar sobre as funções não terem sido declarada quando usadas.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas no caso de ter um ponteiro na Main, na primeira função passo um ponteiro para o ponteiro, dentro dessa função quero chamar outra para que tambem modifique essa estrutura, como já tenho um ponteiro de ponteiro, passo assim? Ou tenho que passar o endereço do ponteiro de ponteiro? Espero que tenha entendido

Comment: Sim, pode, fazendo `**a=1`, por exemplo. Se vc já tem um ponteiro pra ponteiro e quer "repassá-lo" para outra função que já recebe esse tipo de dado, é só fazer a chamada `bar(a)` normalmente. Aliás, tudo o que eu descrevi continua válido, basta imaginar que `**a` é o equivalente a `*(*a)`. Se tiver dúvidas ainda, depois das duas respostas que já teve, sugiro fortemente que leia as outras perguntas que eu citei e faça uns exercícios (imprimindo os valores de `a`, `&a` e `*a`). Vai te ajudar um bocado.