# O que é ponteiro para ponteiro?

Tags: c, ponteiro

Como se deve usar *ponteiro para ponteiro*? Tenho dificuldade em distinguir oque é **endereço de memória** e **valor na memória** quando eu tento usar ponteiro para ponteiro, isso me parece misterioso. Alguém poderia me dar uma explicação e um exemplo do uso de *ponteiro para ponteiro*?

Minha tentativa de implementação de *ponteiro para ponteiro*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    //Este código gera um erro. E não exibe o valor da variável "ponteiroDoPonteiro".

    int *ponteiro, **ponteiroDoPonteiro, valor;

    valor = 50;
    ponteiro = &valor;

    *ponteiroDoPonteiro = &ponteiro;

    printf("\n%d", **ponteiroDoPonteiro);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Em `*ponteiroDoPonteiro = &ponteiro;` você não devia usar o `*` - pois assim você está dizendo que o *valor* do `int**` (i.e. um `int*`) deve ser o *endereço* de um `int*` (i.e. um `int**`). Eu não tenho como dar uma resposta completa no momento, mas uma aproximação razoável é a seguinte: toda vez que você coloca um `&` na frente o tipo do resultado ganha um `*` a mais; toda vez que você coloca um `*` na frente o tipo do resultado fica com um `*` a menos. :)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Vamos dizer que cada célula de memória do computador corresponde a uma casa. Estas casas estão todas organizadas em uma única rua e cada casa tem um número. Este número da casa é o **endereço**. Dentro de cada casa, existe alguém morando, e este morador (que também é um número) é o **valor armazenado**. No caso de um ponteiro para ponteiro, temos o número de alguma casa, e ao olhar dentro desta casa, encontramos um morador que é um número. O número que este morador tem representa o número de alguma outra casa que tem algum outro morador.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O erro já foi apontado pelo comentário do mgibsonbr. Você não pode armazenar um endereço (quando se usa o `&` está dizendo para pegar o endereço) como um valor de ponteiro. Você coloca o endereço no próprio ponteiro (lembre-se que `*variavel` está dizendo que quer o valor apontado pelo ponteiro).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int valor = 50;
    int *ponteiro = &valor;
    int **ponteiroDoPonteiro = &ponteiro; //note que a variável realmente já é um ponteiro
//o que está na posição da memória apontada pela posição da memória de ponteiroDoPonteiro
    printf("\n%d", **ponteiroDoPonteiro);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/BKiU6B). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ucnscsnp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/ToPointer.c).

O ponteiro de ponteiro é muito usado em vetores onde simula várias dimensões, mas o uso mais comum é na simulação de um vetor de *strings*. Se existisse o conceito de *string* na linguagem e o *array* fosse tratado de forma um pouco diferente, seriam raros os casos de uso de ponteiro de ponteiro.

Obviamente pode ter mais níveis, mas é mais raro achar aplicação para ele.

Acho que os detalhes podem ser obtidos em [outra resposta aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25359/101) que remete a outra no SO.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, clareou um pouco. Tinha muita dificuldade de entender este funcionamento de *ponteiro para ponteiro*.

Comment: Pela referencia li sobre ponteiro de ponteiro ser o mesmo que array de array, citando string, ate ai tudo bem já tinha pensado nisso, mas não tinha pensado que `*****p` seria um o mesmo que um array penta dimensional. Interessante.

Answer (score 12):

Um ponteiro é uma variável que guarda o endereço de memória de uma outra variável, ambos do mesmo tipo.

Um ponteiro para um ponteiro consiste em uma variável que guarda o endereço de outra, essa outra por sua vez guarda o endereço da variável que tem um tipo de dado "comum".
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na prática o conceito pode ser visto da seguinte forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *ponteiro, **ponteiroDoPonteiro, valor;
    valor = 50;
    ponteiro = &valor;
    ponteiroDoPonteiro = &ponteiro;
    printf("\nValor de ponteiroDoPonteiro: %p\nEndereço de memoria de ponteiro: %p\nValor de ponteiro: %p\nEndereco de memoria de valor: %p\nValor: %d", ponteiroDoPonteiro, &ponteiro, ponteiro, &valor, valor);
    return 0;
}
```

O problema do código já foi apontado duas vezes no comentário e na resposta, ao tentar fazer `*ponteiroDoPonteiro = &ponteiro;` você esta tentado colocar o endereço de `ponteiro` no valor de `ponteiroDoPonteiro`, que não existe se o mesmo não aponta para nada.

Tire o `*` que terás sucesso.

Comment: Sim eu consegui resolver. Obrigado pela explicação já estou começando a entender melhor o funcionamento de *ponteiro para ponteiro*.