# Um ponteiro global pode apontar para uma variável local?

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, memória

No caso abaixo, por exemplo:

```
int *pnum;
void main(){
  int num = 10;
  pnum = &num;
}
```

O que aconteceria se eu tentasse acessar o valor apontado do ponteiro fora da função main ?

Comment: O programa teria comportamento anômalo porque você está apontando para um frame da pilha, criado quando você entra na função e descartado quando você sai da função, então está apontando para "terra de ninguém". Há soluções porcas para isso e.g. tornar a variável static, aí ela vai continuar existindo depois da função sair, mas dificilmente isto poderia ser considerado boa prática.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vamos colocar um código real para ver o que acontece:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int *pnum;
void teste() {
    printf("%d\n", *pnum);
}
void teste2() {
    int num = 20;
    pnum = &num;
}
void teste3() {
    int num = 30;
    num++;
}
int main() {
    int num = 10;
    pnum = &num;
    teste();
    teste2();
    teste3();
    teste();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/A3mybb). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yrvwiewm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/GlobalLocal.c).

O problema não é a variável ser global. É ela apontar para uma variável local. O código só deveria ter um ponteiro apontando para um [endereço local (*stack*) ou no *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). O que acontece se não respeitar isto?

Códigos assim podem apontar para valores arbitrários, para endereços que não possuem dados garantidos.

Quando chamamos a função `teste()`, ela executa normalmente e pega o valor correto, afinal o endereço do ponteiro é uma área da pilha que está preservada. O *stack frame* da função `main()` não desaparece quando chama outra função. Pelo contrário, um é empilhado no outro.

Note que a linguagem não garante isto. Mas é assim que costuma funcionar. O risco é seu. Se souber o que está fazendo vai dar tudo certo.

Aí chamamos `teste2()` que muda o valor do ponteiro. Agora ele aponta para a variável local desta função e não mais para a função `main()`. Esta variável tem outro valor. Até aí tudo bem.

Agora chamamos `teste3()`. Note que criamos uma variável local com novo valor. Mas não mudamos o ponteiro para apontar para esta variável. Ele continuará apontando para a variável local de `teste2()`, certo?

Mas como isto é possível se aquela variável não existe mais? Bem, o endereço de memória continua lá, está apontando pra ele. O que acontece agora?

Chamamos o `teste()` que imprime o valor da variável local de `teste3()` que nunca foi referenciado pelo ponteiro `pnum`. Por que isto ocorre?

Porque no fim da função `teste2()` o seu conteúdo é desempilhado. Não é apagado, mas fica livre para uso. Com a chamada da `teste3()`, é empilhado no mesmo lugar onde tinha os dados da `teste2()`. Por coincidência o valor da variável local de `teste3()` foi colocado no mesmo lugar onde estava a variável local de `teste2()`. Mas foi só uma coincidência. Deu sorte, podia ser pior.

Quando você vai subindo a pilha dá até para prever que valores estarão na pilha, mas quando você desce da pilha, qualquer valor que tenha lá deve ser considerado lixo e não deve ser acessado. A linguagem não impede.

Os dois principais motivos para existir o *heap* são: ter dados muito grandes que poderiam estourar a pilha ou justamente poder ter dados "vivos" criados por uma função mais alta sendo acessados por funções mais baixas em endereço "garantido".

Answer (score 4):

Sim, como o ponteiro aponta para o endereço da memória é possível modificar as variáveis locais através de um ponteiro global ou simplesmente passando o endereço da sua variável local para um ponteiro como parâmetro para uma função `f(&ponteiro)` ou para um ponteiro global `int * pGlobal;`, veja um exemplo abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int * pGlobal;

void foo(void)
{
    *pGlobal = 100;
}

int main(void)
{
    int num = 15;

    pGlobal = &num;

    printf("\n%d", *pGlobal);
    printf("\n%d", num);

    *pGlobal = 5;

    printf("\n%d", *pGlobal);
    printf("\n%d", num);

    foo();

    printf("\n%d", *pGlobal);
    printf("\n%d", num);

    return 0;
}
```

Acessando e modificando a variável declarada na função main:

```
void foo(void)
{
    *pGlobal = 100;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/qMI6SJ).

Veja mais sobre ponteiros aqui nesta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92823/o-que-%C3%A9-ponteiro-para-ponteiro).

Answer (score 3):

A memória pode ser dividida em duas áreas: **pilha** (*stack*) e **monte** (*heap*). Memória alocada por meio de `malloc` e desalocada com `free` é a memória que está no **monte**. Já as variáveis locais estão na **pilha**.

A implementação exata da pilha depende de detalhes como o compilador usado, o sistema operacional, o conjunto de instruções do processador e detalhes da arquitetura da sua máquina.

Entretanto, apesar das diferenças, a estrutura da pilha na memória tem estruturas parecidas. Ela é chamada de **pilha** porque as chamadas de funções (*stack frame*) são empilhadas umas sobre as outras nesta região da memória. Dentro de cada chamada de função, também são empilhadas as variáveis locais e também uma coisa chamada de endereço de retorno, que é a posição na qual a execução da função deve prosseguir quando a função invocada a seguir terminar.

Desta forma se tivermos um caso aonde a função `main()` chama `a()` que por sua vez chama `b()`, a pilha ficará mais ou menos como o abaixo. Note que o começo da pilha está no endereço 4072 e que cada variável ocupa uma porção da memória da pilha, cada qual com o seu tamanho:

```
+---------------------------------------+
+ 4072-4075: variável local 1 do main() +
+ 4076-4079: variável local 2 do main() + <--- Stack frame do main()
+ 4080-4087: endereço de retorno        +
+---------------------------------------+
+ 4088-4089: variável local 1 de a()    +
+ 4090-4093: variável local 2 de a()    +
+ 4094-4095: variável local 3 de a()    + <--- Stack frame do a()
+ 4096-4099: variável local 4 de a()    +
+ 4100-4107: endereço de retorno        +
+---------------------------------------+
+ 4108-4109: variável local 1 de b()    +
+ 4110-4119: variável local 2 de b()    + <--- Stack frame do b()
+ 4120-4127: variável local 3 de b()    +
+ 4128-4135: variável local 4 de b()    +
+---------------------------------------+
+ 4128-9999: Espaço livre na pilha....  +
+---------------------------------------+
```

Vamos supor que `b()` retorne o endereço da sua variável local 3 (4120) para `a()`. Desta forma, após `b()` retornar, a pilha fica assim:

```
+---------------------------------------+
+ 4072-4075: variável local 1 do main() +
+ 4076-4079: variável local 2 do main() + <--- Stack frame do main()
+ 4080-4087: endereço de retorno        +
+---------------------------------------+
+ 4088-4089: variável local 1 de a()    +
+ 4090-4093: variável local 2 de a()    + <--- Stack frame do a()
+ 4094-4095: variável local 3 de a()    +
+ 4096-4099: variável local 4 de a()    +
+---------------------------------------+
+ 4100-9999: Espaço livre na pilha....  +
+---------------------------------------+
```

Neste ponto, o endereço que `b()` retornou (4110) é um endereço não utilizado na pilha, e portanto se `a()` utilizar este endereço para algo, poderá causar uma falha de segmentação, corromper a memória, ou ler lixo na memória que `b()` tiver deixado para trás. Mas independente do caso, **isso é comportamento indefinido.**

A coisa fica engraçada, se `a()` chamar `c(int *)` passando este endereço obtido de `b` como parâmetro, e supondo que o tamanho do ponteiro seja de 8 bytes:

```
+---------------------------------------+
+ 4072-4075: variável local 1 do main() +
+ 4076-4079: variável local 2 do main() + <--- Stack frame do main()
+ 4080-4087: endereço de retorno        +
+---------------------------------------+
+ 4088-4089: variável local 1 de a()    +
+ 4090-4093: variável local 2 de a()    +
+ 4094-4095: variável local 3 de a()    + <--- Stack frame do a()
+ 4096-4099: variável local 4 de a()    +
+ 4100-4107: endereço de retorno        +
+---------------------------------------+
+ 4108-4115: parâmetro 1 de c()         +
+ 4116-4123: variável local 1 de c()    + <--- Stack frame do c()
+ 4124-4169: variável local 2 de c()    +
+---------------------------------------+
+ 4170-9999: Espaço livre na pilha....  +
+---------------------------------------+
```

Observe que neste caso o endereço 4120 vai cair no meio de uma variável de `c()`. Aliás, pior que isso, metade em cada uma das variáveis. Quando `c()` tentar alterar o valor contido neste endereço, estará corrompendo as suas próprias variáveis. Desnecessário dizer que o resultado disso provavelmente é catastrófico.