# Variavel Global C++

Tags: c++

Tenho esse código

```
int main() {
    ListaVend lista;
    criarLista(&lista);
    for(int i = 0; i <= VEND_MAX; i++){
        Vendedor vend;
        vend.codVend = i;
        vend.nome = "Vendedor "+to_string(i);
        vend.salFinal = i;
        inserLista(&lista, &vend, i);
    }
    showLista(lista);
```

Dessa forma ele funciona normal. Agora eu queria que a Variavel fosse acessada fora do main tambem, como eu posso fazer isso?

Ps.

```
ListaVend lista;
int main() {
    criarLista(&lista);
    for(int i = 0; i <= VEND_MAX; i++){
        Vendedor vend;
        vend.codVend = i;
        vend.nome = "Vendedor "+to_string(i);
        vend.salFinal = i;
        inserLista(&lista, &vend, i);
    }
    showLista(lista);
```

Desta forma não salva nenhuma informação na Lista.

Comment: Se for utilizar fora do main em uma outra função, pode pode passar ela por "referência" da mesma forma que utilizou na função criarLista.

Comment: Então, só que eu quero criar um "menu" para poder manipular essa lista. Por exemplo, acesso o main chama o menu, do menu acesso a opção inserir, depois de inserir volto para o menu... entendeu?

Comment: Só com esse trecho não dá para saber o que está acontecendo. Mas de qualquer forma não faça isso. Não existe motivo algum pra fazer. Tem motivos para não fazer.

Comment: Pelo que pude ver só com esse trecho "deveria" funcionar; sem saber o que esse criarLista() funciona fica difícil mas, me parece, que lista é uma lista de "Vendedor" não? Porque você não "usa vector<vendedor> lista" ?

Comment: Desculpe, aqui esta meu código completo: http://pastebin.com/eX9dZPqk 
É que estou aprendendo listas na faculdade, ai queria fazer esse "menu" para poder deixar mais bonito e funcional

Comment: Tenta passar a lista como ponteiro em showlista:  showLista(&lista);

Comment: Vê se ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99551/101 Mas reforço, o ideal é não fazer isso. E acho uma pena que em uma faculdade se ensine misturar C com C++.

Comment: Entendi Perry, vou tentar implementar isso. E Bigown vou dar uma lida melhor nessa question.

Answer (score 3):

No geral seu programa está certo, com as seguintes ressalvas:

estas funções

```
bool cheiaLista(ListaVend);    // BAD
bool vaziaLista(ListaVend);    // BAD
void showLista(ListaVend);     // BAD
```

deveriam ser declaradas com parâmetros ponteiro ou referência, assim

```
bool cheiaLista(ListaVend*);   // GOOD
bool vaziaLista(ListaVend*);   // GOOD
void showLista(ListaVend*);    // GOOD
```

ou assim

```
bool cheiaLista(ListaVend&);   // GOOD
bool vaziaLista(ListaVend&);   // GOOD
void showLista(ListaVend&);    // GOOD
```

para evitar cópias na passagens dos parâmetros para essas funções, o que é um negócio **extremamente** ineficiente (além de, no caso geral, obrigar a implementar os contrutores de cópia).

Além disso existe um erro de lógica: isto aqui

```
for (int i = 0; i <= VEND_MAX; i++) {
```

deveria ser assim

```
for (int i = 0; i < VEND_MAX; i++) {
```

Da maneira que você implementou suas funções até parece que vai funcionar, mas essa comparação `i <= VEND_MAX` em C++ é contra-intuitiva, atrapalha o raciocínio, além de estar criando um vendedor a mais que não está sendo inserido na lista.

Comment: Então, nas funções de cheia, vazia e show não utilizei referência pois o professor disse "Só use referência se for alterar algo".

Comment: Se você não usar referência ou ponteiro vai ser feita uma cópia. Se o parâmetro é simples (int, ponteiro, etc) isso não é problema, mas se você tem um objeto com (por exemplo) 50Kb então será feita uma cópia desse objeto de 50 Kb para passar como parâmetro para a função! Existem outras considerações ainda, mas só esse fato da cópia já é suficiente para (quase) sempre usar ponteiro ou referência para instâncias de classe (e lembre-se: uma struct é uma classe), strings, etc, tipos de dados "grandes".

Comment: Mais uma coisinha que vi no seu código, isto é reduntante: `return (lista.n == VEND_MAX) ? true : false;`, use `return (lista.n == VEND_MAX);` ...na verdade os parênteses são opcionais, poderia ser assim `return lista.n == VEND_MAX;` mas aí depende da pessoa